# Can we apply stored procedure in mvvm? explain with reason

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here, I am confused about stored procedure. HERE, we apply all the data base related operation into the code :

```
string query = "insert into accounts(name, opening_balance, category, address, contact_person, phone_number) values("
                                + "'" + account.Name + "',"
                                + account.OpeningBalance + ","
                                + account.Category.Id + ","
                                + "'" + account.Address + "',"
                                + "'" + account.ContactPerson + "',"
                                + "'" + account.PhoneNumber + "')";
            account.Id = SQLiteHelper.ExecuteInsert(query);
```

Can we apply it in stored procedure? If so: how? What is the advantage of stored procedure over it?

Comment: Your code may have SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: MVVM and stored procedures are orthogonal - you can use both or each separately.

Comment: @Oded :hey ,u can see i code we are using sqlite database.in sqlite store procedure apply?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't. If the database supports stored procedures, the data provider libraries would allow you to use them.

Comment: @MarkByers :hey ,this is desktop application.in desktop application SQL injection occur?

Comment: @prjndhi: **YES!** You should **never** concatenate together a SQL statement - [use **parametrized queries** instead](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) - **always!** No exception.

Comment: @marc_s :but can we apply  parametrized queries in mvvm?

Comment: @prjndhi: the `model` part of your MVVM can be anything - and that includes a **parametrized** stored procedure, yes, of course - what makes you think you couldn't use it??

Comment: @marc_s :at that time POCO created ?

Comment: Why SQLLlite? Why not SQL Server, MySQL or even MS Access?

Comment: @marko :we create desktop application and sqlite has been used with great success as the on disk file format for desktop application.so we are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVVM has nothing to do with your SQL question.

Basically you should not string together values into a SQL expression, as it allows for the injection of SQL code by the end-user. ie. *really bad idea*.

A stored procedure give you more control over the parameters and avoids injection attacks. It also allows you to make subtle changes, e.g. if the database changes slightly, without changing the calling C# code.

Unfortunately it appears that SQLite does not support store procs, so you may want to vary your approach. Take a look at this link: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

If you must stick with SQLite, and not say SQL CE, you will want to add validation checks to your code to ensure SQL statements are not inserted.

Comment: hey,this project is doing as desktop application.if we want to use it as web APPLICATION then we will change view as silver light .but at that time we may not use sqlite according to drawback.then we have to change all the query in file to convert in SP?

Comment: You should change your queries anyway as they are not safe, but if you do go to a web application you can use a proper SQL server. You should be using Entity Framework & LINQ to SQL rather than plain SQL commands if you can. Entity Framework & LINQ are both designed to make database work much easier to code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check the values in the inserts in the sql to avoid
   sql-injection.
2. Data-access code shouldn't be in the viewmodel. It should be in the model.